# Calling REST API in Angular JS not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fetch data from REST API but it results blank.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**hello.js**

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
        });
});
```

**output:**

```
The ID is

The content is
```

ID and content is still missing. Any help please?

**Edit**:(FIX) Problem was with a plugin installed in the browser, which weren't allowing web service. Thanks everyone.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: this is code is working just fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/iufKaW1hfHUXzYOWd1b9?p=preview.  The problem must be something to do with your environment or something you aren't showing here.

Comment: `angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
        }, function(error){
           console.log(error);
        };
});`

Try this and inspect the error on browser console. if There is no error then the you have to check the api return data property.

Comment: Are you sure it's not showing anything? Because your code works for me. As @Claies said, check your console for any possible errors.

Comment: Its working  properly. Debug on browser console. This is the values I get returned `content:"Hello, World!"
id:886`

Answer (score 1):

Well Seems like your api return following response:
    {
        "id": 879,
        "content": "Hello, World!"
    }

try fetching response.content for accessing message

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code in my local. I observed that if you replace http from https in you request, it wont work. Try to run this from file protocol in your browser and it will work as shown in the picture.[image]

Also the api you mentioned is now working over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your controller with following  one

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        var callMethod = function() {
            $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting')
                .then(function(response) {
                        $scope.greeting = response.data;
                        alert($scope.greeting.id);
                        alert($scope.greeting.content);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        }

        callMethod();
    });
```